# How do I limit the number of values in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with many different values, like the following:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For this example lets say I only want to display the top 3 numbers or `<li>` elements. How can I do this? I feel like the answer is really simple but I cannot for the life of me remember how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, if you want to show only three `li` elements:

```
$('li:gt(2)').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LCeNx/).

With CSS:

```
li:nth-child(3) ~ li {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LCeNx/2/).

If you want to hide all `li` elements with text-values that are greater than `3`:

```
$('li').filter(function () {
    return parseFloat($.trim($(this).text())) > 3;
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LCeNx/3/).

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$('ul').children().hide().slice(0,3).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('li:gt(2)').hide();
```

to only show the top three `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
        $(function(){
            $( "#sample_div > ul >li:gt(2)" ).hide();
        })
```

HTML CODE

```
    <div id="sample_div">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, and also change the hider callback in any way.

```
$.fn.showOnly = function(n) {
    return $(this).each(function(i) {
        if (i < n) $(this).show();
        else $(this).hide();
    });
};

$("ul li").showOnly(2);
```